# Can I made use of comprehensions for comparing these lists of dictionaries?

Tags: python, network-programming, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

As title. I'm trying to figure out a comprehension for this. Getting stuck adding complexity to the basic code I built so far. I feel like this would actually be easier in a comprehension, but I couldn't find an example to build off of, so a jumpstart would be appreciated.

Scope:

1. Try to match the list elements by dictionary's "network" value. Failing to find a match for old_routes' elements in new_routes should print a warning.
2. If a match between the lists "network" value is found, compare those dictionaries' "nexthop_ip", and print whether the new_route's nexthop_ip has changed or stayed the same.
3. I may need to run #2 comparison on other values as well.

Thanks in advance.

```
old_routes = [
    {
        "network": "10.11.11.11",
        "distance": "20",
        "metric": "0",
        "nexthop_ip": "10.155.155.155",
    },
    {
        "network": "10.22.22.22",
        "distance": "20",
        "metric": "0",
        "nexthop_ip": "10.99.99.99",
    },
    {
        "network": "10.33.33.33",
        "distance": "20",
        "metric": "0",
        "nexthop_ip": "10.66.66.66",
    }
]
new_routes = [
    {
        "network": "10.11.11.11",
        "distance": "20",
        "metric": "0",
        "nexthop_ip": "10.155.155.155",
    },
    {
        "network": "10.22.22.22",
        "distance": "20",
        "metric": "0",
        "nexthop_ip": "10.77.77.77",
    }
]

for old_route in old_routes:
    for new_route in new_routes:
        if old_route["network"] == new_route["network"]:
            if old_route["nexthop_ip"] == new_route["nexthop_ip"]:
                print(f"{new_route['network']} has no routing changes.")
            else:
                print(f"{new_route['network']} has changed nexthop IPs from {old_route['nexthop_ip']} to {new_route['nexthop_ip']}")
```

Comment: Comprehensions are used to put all the results of a generator in a collection: list, set, or dictionary. You're not saving the results anywhere, you're just printing messages.

Comment: I think what you're actually looking for is the `any()` function, which has nothing to do with comprehensions.

Comment: I'm guessing you ran into performance problems (comparing every dictionary from `old_routes` to every dictionary in `new_routes`). You should make an index to speed up the search.

Comment: Instead of using lists of routes, use a dictionary where the keys are networks.

Comment: it isn't clear what you want the output to be, actually. but in general, you shouldn't worry about creating a *list comprehension*. You should worry about creating code that is 1) efficient, 2) readable/maintainable. A list comprehension is for expressing mapping/filtering operations from an arbitrary iterable to create *a list*. But that doesn't sound like you want that

Comment: so, what you probably *should* be doing is using a `dict` instead of a `list` for `old_routes` (you could make one using a dictionary comprehension, although, not if the networks aren't unique) then simply use that dict to lookup any network in "new routes" and compare with the `nexthop_ip` value

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
old_networks = set(route["network"] for route in old_routes)
new_networks = set(route["network"] for route in new_routes)

for network in old_networks - new_networks:
    print(f"Warning: {network} not found in new_routes")

for new_route in new_routes:
    try:
        old_route = next(route for route in old_routes if route["network"] == new_route["network"])
        if old_route["nexthop_ip"] == new_route["nexthop_ip"]:
            print(f"{new_route['network']} has no routing changes.")
        else:
            print(f"{new_route['network']} has changed nexthop IPs from {old_route['nexthop_ip']} to {new_route['nexthop_ip']}")
    except StopIteration:
        print(f"Warning: {new_route['network']} not found in old_routes")
```

The first portion takes care of routes that are missing from `new_routes` and the second takes care of requirement #2 (compares IPs and then nexthop).